# How to Set default-character-set to utf8 by mysql 5.58 in mac os 10.6.5

Tags: mysql, macos

I copy my.cnf to etc folder and [client] [mysqld] set ault-character-set = utf8 but server not start ,In mac os 10.6.5 ,How to Set ddefault-character-set to utf8 by mysql 5.58 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[client]
default-character-set=charset_name
```

source : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-configuration.html

more on charset configuration - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_default-character-set